# My code gives me an error message: GetElementById() is null or not an object

Tags: javascript

I have this js code:

```
var id = document.getElementById("myDiv").getAttribute("data-id");  

et="Your Message Here";
el="http://x2.xclicks.net/sc/out.php?s="+id+""
sl=new Array(); 
sn=new Array();
a="</a>"; af="<a target='_blank'";


function dw(n) {document.write(n,"\n");}
function showLink(n,s,b){
    if(!s) {s='anc'} 
    if(!b) {b=''} 
    else   {b="&b="+b}
    ast = af+" class='"+s+"' href='"+el; 
    n   = n-1; 
    if(sl[n]&&sl[n]!="") {
        dw(ast+"&o="+sl[n]+b+"'>"+sn[n]+a)
    } else {
        dw(ast+b+"'>"+et+a)
    }
}
```

Which I load in my header.php like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<? bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/trf.js"></script>
```

The problem is that although this is correct:

```
var id = document.getElementById("myDiv").getAttribute("data-id");
```

I get this error:

**getElementById() is null or not an object**

Ady Ideas why?

Do I need to declare a document ready or something?

Comment: What does your markup look like?

Comment: Don't use javascript for this task. Just output the link with the right url directly, you know it serverside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need to declare a document ready or something?

Yes, exactly. Before the document is ready (ie all tags are parsed to DOM elements), you won't be able to get elements by id. This would only work for elements above your script tag, which are already parsed. Moving the script inclusion from `<head>` before the end of `</body>` would help. Alternatively you'll need to use one of the various `DOMContentLoaded` or `onload` events, which unfortunately are not cross-browser supported. I recommend to search for a good snippet or use a library.

Comment: If I use document ready the code does not work. It needs to be loaded first, before the dom. So is there another way to get the value of the id that will make this work?

Comment: Yes, you should not use `document.write`. If you need it, you will need to move the script behind the `#myDiv` element. You can't access it from before.

Comment: I generate the id value with php. Can I put the id value in an ellement before the <head> like a link rel="" or something?

Comment: Yes, but why don't you put the data directly into the script? Or even better, just output the link instead of calling a javascript?

Comment: 1. I think its not possible to put php code into my js. 2. The links are generated externally, not on my site - its something like google ads 3. Ty for helping btw:) - what element should I use inside the <head> to put my id value in order to retrieve it with js?

Comment: @1: Oh, surely you can. The PHP will be executed serverside and generate a dynamic script that will be evaluated clientside. `<script>var data = "<? echo $datastring; ?>"; …`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're loading that script in the `<head>` of your document, you are trying to get an element by ID when that element is not yet loaded into the DOM.

You will need to wait for your document to be ready (via `onDOMContentLoaded`, `window.onload`, or any other way of deferring until rendering is complete) in order to access that element by ID.

Answer (score 1):

I would try wrapping it in a `$(document).ready`. More than likely you're just trying to access it before the DOM is ready

Comment: If I use document ready the code does not work. It needs to be loaded first, before the dom.

Comment: @webmasters well that doesn't really make sense. The DOM, or Document Object Model, contains all of the objects, or elements, in your document. It is accessed by the `document` object in javascript. So, before the DOM is ready, `document.getElementById(anything)` is going to be null

Comment: @webmasters to clarify, there is no possible way to access values of any element in your document before the DOM is ready. Period. The only exception, I guess, would be if you knew ahead of time what the value of the element is going to be (maybe if you're getting it from the server), then you could just intercept it from the server. But that's a whole different question entirely

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt: You can access all elements that are already parsed. If you put the script directly after the div, it will be available.

Comment: What html element can I use to place the ID value before the <head> section of a site? I generate the id using php.

Comment: @Bergi right, but it seems to me that he wants the value around the time the header is evaluated, which is always going to be before anything is ready

Comment: @webmasters you're gonna have to rephase that question, I didn't quite understand

Answer (score 0):

You're loading the script in the header, which means that the script is being loaded before the rest of the document. Inside the script, you're calling document.getElementById straight away, and since the rest of the document hasn't finished loading the chances are extremely high the element you're after won't exist yet.

You need to delay running that part of the script until the document is fully loaded. Wrap that part of the script in a function, and call it during the body.onload event.

As an example (there are other ways to achieve the same result):

```
window.document.onload = function(e){ 
    var id = document.getElementById("myDiv").getAttribute("data-id");  

    // Now you have the id and can do whatever you want with it.
}
```

Comment: If I use document ready the code does not work. It needs to be loaded first, before the dom. So is there another way to get the value of the id that will make this work?

Comment: You're *using* the dom, so saying this needs to work "before the dom" makes no sense. You want to get hold of an element before that element even exists - how is that going to work?